# Error while installing package in RStudio

Tags: r, r-package

I'm not able to install the **IntroCompFinR** package in RStudio due to this error:

```
> install.packages("IntroCompFinR")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/HP/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘IntroCompFinR’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [R-Forge repo](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1465)?

```
install.packages("IntroCompFinR", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

You may also have to install `quadprog` from another repo first.

```
install.packages("quadprog", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com")
install.packages("IntroCompFinR", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

Comment: thanks,, the first one worked.
install.packages("IntroCompFinR", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")

Answer (score 0):

`install.packages("package_name")` from `devtools` library works only when the package is enlisted in CRAN, and complies with your R version.

Three alternatives if it is available, but either not in CRAN or not compatible with your R version:

- **Install via Github:** If your package is incorporated in a Github repository (most packages are), then you can use

```r
install_github("github_UsernameOfAuthor/repository_name")
```

Other prominent repository holders include bitbucket and gitorious, for which

```r
install_bitbucket("package_Author/repository_name")
```

and

```r
install_gitorious("package_Author/repository_name")
```

apply respectively.

- **Install via R-Forge:** If your repository is uploaded to R-Forge, you can use

```r
install.packages("package_name", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

This is applicable in your case since there is an R-Forge repository for the **IntroCompFinR** library, with the install command being mentioned [here](https://github.com/rforge/introcompfinr) as well.

- **Install via some other source URL/website:** If your package has a repository somewhere on the internet, you can use the source-link to install the package via

```r
install.packages("package_name", repos="URL")`.
```

**Note**: All of these commands are provided by `devtools`, which you seem to have, but just in case you don't, you can use these commands to install both devtools and your required package:

```r
# Install directly from CRAN:
if(!require(devtools))install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install.packages("package_name")

# Install via Github:
if(!require(devtools))install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("githubAuthor_username/package_name")

# Install via R-Forge or any other repository holding website:
if(!require(devtools))install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install.packages("package_name",repos="website-link")
```

Most package authors give installation commands in their package vignette or via their Github repository for the same, but you can acquire the package directly provided you know its name and link to the source repository.

You can use this post as a reference when installing R packages in the future.